# Will the value of isLoading be always true in the Android Jetpack Compose project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

The following code is from the official [Advanced State in Jetpack Compose Codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab).

In the function `fun DetailsScreen()`, `uiState.isLoading -> {...}` will be fired when `isLoading` is true.

I searched all the code in the project, I can only find the code `val uiState by produceState(initialValue = DetailsUiState(isLoading = true))` to pass value to `isLoading`.

Will `uiState.isLoading -> {...}` always be fired in the project?

```
data class DetailsUiState(
    val cityDetails: ExploreModel? = null,
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val throwError: Boolean = false
)

@Composable
fun DetailsScreen(
    onErrorLoading: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: DetailsViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val uiState by produceState(initialValue = DetailsUiState(isLoading = true)) {
        val cityDetailsResult = viewModel.cityDetails
        value = if (cityDetailsResult is Result.Success<ExploreModel>) {
            DetailsUiState(cityDetailsResult.data)
        } else {
            DetailsUiState(throwError = true)
        }
    }

    when {
        uiState.cityDetails != null -> {
            DetailsContent(uiState.cityDetails!!, modifier.fillMaxSize())
        }
        uiState.isLoading -> {
            Box(modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                )
            }
        }
        else -> { onErrorLoading() }
    }
}


@HiltViewModel
class DetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val destinationsRepository: DestinationsRepository,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel() {

    private val cityName = savedStateHandle.get<String>(KEY_ARG_DETAILS_CITY_NAME)!!

    val cityDetails: Result<ExploreModel>
        get() {
            val destination = destinationsRepository.getDestination(cityName)
            return if (destination != null) {
                Result.Success(destination)
            } else {
                Result.Error(IllegalArgumentException("City doesn't exist"))
            }
        }
}

sealed class Result<out R> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No

The default value of `isLoading` is `false`:

```kotlin
val isLoading: Boolean = false,
```

So the constructor calls that don't explicitly set it to `true` (`DetailsUiState(throwError = true)` and `DetailsUiState(throwError = true)`) will result in it being `false`.

Comment: Thanks! Why will `DetailsUiState(throwError = true))`  will cause `isLoading` as false?

Comment: @HelloCW In Kotlin, parameters that aren't passed get their default values.  Since only `throwError` is passed, `cityDetails` and `isLoading` get their default values, which are, respectively, `null` and `false`.

Comment: And more, I think that the business logic should be this, `isLoading` is true when `cityDetails` is loading, and `isLoading` is assigned to false after `cityDetails` has been loaded.

But I can't find any code in the project `isLoading` is assigned to false after `cityDetails` has been loaded!

Comment: @HelloCW I think I understand your confusion now.  Each of those is creating a **new** `DetailsUiState`, not changing the old one.  Note that all the fields of `DetailsUiState` are `val`s - it's immutable.

Comment: Thanks! I think the value of `uiState.isLoading` should always false because either `DetailsUiState(cityDetailsResult.data)` or `DetailsUiState(throwError = true)` will get the object with the value `isLoading = false` by default in this `fun DetailsScreen`  , right?

Comment: @HelloCW Correct, in those scenarios, `isLoading` would be `false`.